# wxpython: How to pass XY coordinator and draw it out?

Tags: python, wxpython, drawing

I'm new for python but willing to learn. I have a set of hardware to receive touch coordinators and draw line accordingly to coordinators.

My problem is that the wxpython won't draw line if coordinator changes.
Here is my code : https://github.com/eleghostliu/homework/blob/master/DrawXY_byWxPython/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1.py

can someone give advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered for `EVT_PAINT`, yet **you are not triggering the event** as the data changes. The frame has no idea whether data changed or not, unless you specifically inform it.

You can trigger the event simply by calling

`frame.Refresh()`

You can hook it in several ways. For instance, you could pass `frame.Refresh` bound method as a parameter to `MainProcess` so that it can make the function call to refresh the frame. Something like the following:

*WARNING: Erroneous code piece*

```
# Start a socket server
def MainProcess(refresh_callback):
    while True:
        refresh_callback()
***********************************************
frame = DrawPanel()
frame.Show()
start_new_thread(MainProcess, (frame.Refresh,))
```

**Edit:**

**The above code piece calling UI methods directly is wrong!**

Worker thread should not directly manipulate GUI, instead it should inform the GUI thread about a change, and the GUI thread which is the main thread will handle it in its context. There are again several approaches here, the quickest to implement is through [`wx.CallAfter`](https://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter).

Which you can incorporate as below, instead of directly calling the function:

`wx.CallAfter(refresh_callback)`

Another way to handle the communication between worker thread and GUI thread is via [`wx.PostEvent`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html).

```
class DrawPanel(wx.Frame):
    """Draw a line to a panel."""
    def notify(self):
        wx.PostEvent(self, wx.PaintEvent())
```

Then from the secondary thread, you can safely call `frame.notify()` whenever new data arrives.

For a more elegant solution involving `wx.CallAfter`, refer to https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/ where `pubsub` is used.

Comment: thanks. it works. But the line doesn't continuous, only two points can be connected a line. I attempted to mark dc.Clear() but still not work.

Comment: Please refer my revision code, 
https://github.com/eleghostliu/homework/blob/master/DrawXY_byWxPython/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1.py

it got flickering screen issue, it shows all the track of line and disappear (Not sure if caused by dc.Clear()), and show all the track of line next frame.

Comment: thanks. You said there are several ways to hook it. Can you elaborate other method? key word is fine, example is better.

Comment: Sorry i totally missed the point that **you should not call gui methods from secondary threads directly**. I am editing the last part and giving a proper example for the communication between gui thread and the data gathering thread.